# Flask-Babel fail to extract UTF-8 content

Tags: python, encoding, python-babel, flask-babel

I have a translatable string in one of my Jinja2 templates:

```
Project can’t end sooner than it starts
```

(Note the UTF-8 apostrophe in “can’t”.)

When I extract messages and update my translation files, both the template (`.pot`) and translation (`.po`) files have the following `msgid`:

```
msgid "Project canât end sooner than it starts"
```

It seems Babel “translated” the UTF-8 characters as if they were in some kind of 8-bit character set.

My `babel.cfg` is a really short one:

```
[python: **.py]
[jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
extensions=jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_,webassets.ext.jinja2.AssetsExtension
```

Is there a way for Babel to notice the template is already in UTF-8, and not to transalete it from whatever charset it thinks? I can’t see any related option in the help output of `pybabel extract --help` nor `pybabel extract --help`.

I use Python3 exclusively, for the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it is supported out of the box, it’s just seems undocumented. All I had to do is changing the configuration:

```
[python: **.py]
[jinja2: **/templates/**.html]
encoding=utf-8
extensions=jinja2.ext.autoescape,jinja2.ext.with_,webassets.ext.jinja2.AssetsExtension
```

The `encoding=utf-8` part did its magic, all HTML files are now treated as UTF-8 data.